# Only run PHP code after an HTML post

Tags: php, html

Right now I have code where I display the results of a search but it's running automatically when the page starts, not just after the user enters search. How can I make it so the PHP code runs only after a user enters the submit button?

```
<h1>Search Results</h1> <br />
<ul style="list-style-type:disc" class="indentList">
<?php foreach ($memberName as $value) { ?>
<li><a href="http://buddybosssport.tk/members/<?php echo $value;?>/"><?php echo $value ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

This is the code that's displaying automatically, I only want it to run after the post.

Comment: I don't see any form...

Comment: It is not clear where the form is and how `$memberName` is derived. Please provide complete (simplified, if required) code which shows what you want to achieve, and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the form was submitted, which depends on which method you set for the form.  This will either be POST or GET.

```
<h1>Search Results</h1> <br />
<ul style="list-style-type:disc" class="indentList">
<?php if(isset($_POST['submitbutton'])) { foreach ($memberName as $value) { ?>
<li><a href="http://buddybosssport.tk/members/<?php echo $value;?>/"><?php echo $value ?></a></li>
<?php } }?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check to see if the page was requested via a post request.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    //search resukts
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the form input name is populated in the post.

```
if(isset($_POST['inputname'])) { do stuff }
```

Simples.

For your code:

```
<? if(isset($_POST['inputname'])) { ?>
    <h1>Search Results</h1> <br />
    <ul style="list-style-type:disc" class="indentList">
    <?php foreach ($memberName as $value) { ?>
    <li><a href="http://buddybosssport.tk/members/<?php echo $value;?>/"><?php echo $value ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: But my code to display the information is outside my isset brace because its gathering data from multiple form entries to make one sql statement.